# Type Efficiency: Array{Int64, 1} VERSUS LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{ Int64, Array{Int64, 1}}

Tags: julia

Edited for Clarity!

There are a couple of ways to build/generate an array in Julia.

I have been using the single quote or apostrophe approach for column vectors because it is quicker than multiple commas within the []'s:

```
julia> a = [1 2 3 4]'
4×1 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

This is generating what I believe to be a more complicated data type: "LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}"

In comparison to comma separated elements:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3,4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Which generates an Array{Int64,1} type.

**The Question(s):**

Is the LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{...} type more computationally expensive then the base array? Should I avoid generating this array in a general sense?(i.e. outside modeling linear algebra)

It's possible there is a small difference that wouldn't matter on a smaller scope but, I plan to eventually preform operations on large data sets. Should I try to keep consistent with generating them as Array{Int64,1} types for these purposes?

---

Original

I've been learning Julia and I would like to develop good habits early; focusing on computational efficiency. I have been working with arrays and gotten comfortable with the single quote notation at the end to convert into a column vector. From what I'm understanding about the type system, this isn't just a quicker version than commas way to organize. Is using the comma computationally more expensive or semantically undesirable in general? It seems it wouldn't matter with smaller data sets but, what about larger data sets?(e.g. 10k computations)

```
Deleted original code example to avoid confusion.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'the comma'?

Comment: @DNF, I think he meant apostrophe instead of comma.

Comment: But the question is about the difference between "single quote notation" and "comma". I can't get it to make sense if the intention was to write "apostrophe".

Comment: Oh okay, I understand your comment. Then I believe, by commas, he meant arrays: `[1, 2, 3]` for instance

Comment: He wants to compare efficiency of `Arrays{Int64, 1}` and `LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}`

Comment: In my opinion, this question is very unclear, and needs significant re-writing in order to make it understandable. Although you may be right about your interpretation, @J.Khamphousone, I still cannot tell what sort of reply the poster wants, except perhaps a general essay about the efficiency of lazy data structures.

Comment: I support what @DNF has written. Just one additional comment is that `'` is a **recursive conjugate** transposition operation which is not always what you want.

Comment: Sorry about the vaguely supported question. I just updated it for clarity.

Comment: Recursive Conjugate Transposition Operation... So, I'm preforming a transpose on the vector/matrix/array by using the ```julia ' ```. Does this generate a new type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a performance example:

```
julia> a = rand(10^6);

julia> b = rand(1, 10^6)';

julia> typeof(a)
Array{Float64,1}

julia> typeof(b)
Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}

julia> @btime sum($a)
  270.137 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500428.44363296847

julia> @btime sum($b)
  1.710 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500254.2267732659
```

As you can see, the performance of the sum over the `Vector` is much better than the sum over the `Adjoint` (I'm actually a bit surprised about how big the difference is).

But to me the bigger reason to use `Vector` is that it just seems weird and unnatural to use the complicated and convoluted `Adjoint` type. It is also a much bigger risk that some code will not accept an `Adjoint`, and then you've just made extra trouble for yourself.

But, really, why do you want to use the `Adjoint`? Is it just to avoid writing in commas? How long are these vectors you are typing in? If vector-typing is a very big nuisance to you, you could consider writing `[1 2 3 4][:]` which will return a `Vector`. It will also trigger an extra allocation and copy, and it looks strange, but if it's a very big deal to you, maybe it's worth it.

My advice: type the commas.

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation. I didn't expect the difference to be an order of magnitude.